# How to check Mapbox GL JS Draw state

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

How can you check the state of a `new MapboxDraw` object before sending it to the backend? For example, to show the user some warnings when he tries to submit some actions without creating an object (in my case a polygon) on the map.

```
this.draw = new MapboxDraw({
    controls: {
        trash: true,
        polygon: true
    },
    defaultMode: 'draw_polygon',
    displayControlsDefault: false,
})

# sudocode
if (user has not created a polygon on the map) {
    alert('You must create a polygon before submitting the form!')
}
```

I actually tried to solve this with the following code, because the length value of the correct polygon must be more than 3 points.

```
if (draw.getAll().features[0].geometry.coordinates[0].length <= 3) {
    alert('You must create a polygon before submitting the form!')
}
```

The above code only works in the first execution, but in the second execution it causes an error e.g if user tries to create a Polygon of two points or if user creates one polygon and then removes it

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach many events from Mapbox Draw to your current map.

For example, `map.on('draw.crete', function() {})` This will execute once 1 polygon was already created.

You can also use `draw.getMode()` for catching any type of polygons you draw.

See below example, Hope it helps :)

```
var draw = new mapboxDraw({

    displayControlsDefault: false,
    controls: {
        point: true,
        polygon: true,
        line_string: true,
        trash: true
    }

});

map.on('draw.create', function(e) {

    var drawMode = draw.getMode();
    var drawnFeature = e.features[0];

    switch (drawMode) {
        case 'draw_point':
            // Draw point here
            break;
        case 'draw_polygon':
            // Draw polygon here
            break;
        case 'draw_line_string':
            // Draw linestring here
            break;
        default: alert('no draw options'); break;
    }

});

map.on('draw.update', function(e) {
    // This will call once you edit drawn polygon
});

map.on('draw.delete', function(e) {
    // This will call once you delete any polygon
});
```